# Send an email from user's account after Google Sign In

Tags: android, google-cloud-platform, google-api, gmail-api

What I'm trying to do is send an email (gmail) from the user's behalf after they have signed in with Google Sign in. I've tried following the guides/posts for similar problems, however, I'm not quite sure how to authenticate the user with Gmail after they've logged in with google.

```
 private void handleSignInResult(Task<GoogleSignInAccount> completedTask) {
    try {
        GoogleSignInAccount account = completedTask.getResult(ApiException.class);

        // TODO Send an email from the user's behalf
    } catch (ApiException e) {
        // The ApiException status code indicates the detailed failure reason.
        // Please refer to the GoogleSignInStatusCodes class reference for more information.
        Timber.w(e);
    }
}
```

I am on Android. As you can see I've got `GoogleSignInAccount` from `play-services-auth` (https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/).

Comment: Good question, I'm fighting with it, too. Did you manage to solve it? I'm surprised no one is posting about how to send emails with the Gmail API using Google Sign In results.